# Zend Form in a table

Tags: zend-framework, html-table, zend-form

I have run into a small problem that would otherwise be easy to fix, but due to using the Zend Framework got a bit more complex.

Here's the situation and the problem:
I have a load of data from the database that is displayed in a table. Along with that I have a form that has some fields that are used to filter the data.

Normally I'd solve this by just having the table inside the form tags, however we are now working with a Zend Form and things are a little less easy.

So basically what I want to achieve is the following:

```
<table>
<tr><td> Column 1 </td><td> Column 2 </td><td> Column 3 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Filter 1 </td><td> Filter 2 </td><td> Filter 3 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td></tr>
<tr><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td></tr>
<tr><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td></tr>
<tr><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td></tr>
<tr><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td><td> Data     </td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this? Any advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve here.  The Filter row, is it &ltinput&gt; tags ?

Comment: What i want to achieve is a form inside a table. I want a table with the first row consisting table cells with the column names. The next row to have cells with a form element each for filtering. And then the following rows to have the data i collected from the database.

Comment: How do you filter your form ?  Client side or server side ?  I like to use jQuery to filter my data.  Makes it a lot faster and you don't have to reload.

Comment: Server side, certain filters trigger additional options so i figured to stick with server sided.